# Difference between router path and link path?

Tags: routes, uri

I have recently started looking into the drupal menu system. I am not able to understand the difference between a `router_path` and the `link_path`. Both point to the same location in my installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pro Drupal Development, Second Edition](http://www.drupalbook.com/) describes them as:

> `menu_links.link_path` is the Drupal path or external path this link
>   points to.
>
> `menu_links.router_path` is for links corresponding to a Drupal path
>   (0 means external), this connects the link to a `menu_router.path` for
>   joins.